# Efficient way of setting values of entire row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
    Name    Branch  Course
A   Raja    MECH    DS
B   Amit    CSE     ML
C   Seema   IT      DS
```

Please refer to the dataframe given above. if i want to set values of row at index 0 with

```
 Name= Agam, Branch=ECE & Course= ML,
```

if i write

```
 det.loc["A"] = ["Agam", "ECE", "ML"],
```

(where det is the name of the dataframe shown above), is is correct way to achieve the result , or this result can be achieved through any other efficient way ?

Comment: Please post your dataframe in form of text not the screenshot.

Comment: It is done, kindly check now

Comment: This approach is also good. In case you want to update only two paramter assign like this: `df.loc["A",['Name','Branch']] = ['Agam', 'ECE']`

Comment: i have to set all three ,